# Operations on sets: how to transform the left side to the right side?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could you please give me a detailed description about what is happening here:

$(X_1 \times X_2)\backslash (A_1 \times A_2)=((X_1 \backslash A_1) \times X_2) \cup (X_1 \times(X_2 \backslash A_2))$

?

I know that I can rewrite $(X_1 \times X_2)\backslash (A_1 \times A_2)$ as $(X_1 \times X_2)\cap \overline{(A_1 \times A_2)}$, but I do not understand why the sets on the right side are grouped this way, as much as where the $\cup$ comes from. Moreover, I have never used set operations with the product $\times$. In other words - I do not see how the left side is transformed to the right side.

Will be glad if you help.

p.s. btw. $A_i \subset X_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An arbitrary element of $(X_1 \times X_2) \setminus (A_1 \times A_2)$ is a pair $(x_1,x_2) \in X_1 \times X_2$ such that $(x_1,x_2) \not \in A_1 \times A_2$. To say that $(x_1,x_2) \in A_1 \times A_2$ is precisely to say $x_1 \in A_1 \wedge x_2 \in A_2$, so negating this gives $x_1 \not \in A_1 \vee x_2 \not \in A_2$. This is ultimately where the $\cup$ comes from, as you shall soon see, since we have to split into cases:

- If $x_1 \not \in A_1$, then $x_1 \in X_1 \setminus A_1$ and $x_2 \in X_2$ (regardless of whether it's in $A_2$ or not), so that $(x_1,x_2) \in (X_1 \setminus A_1) \times X_2$;
- If $x_2 \not \in A_2$, then $x_2 \in X_2 \setminus A_2$ and $x_1 \in X_1$ (regardless of whether it's in $A_1$ or not), so that $(x_1,x_2) \in X_1 \times (X_2 \setminus A_2)$.

Putting this together yields $(x_1,x_2) \in ((X_1 \setminus A_1) \times X_2) \cup (X_1 \times (X_2 \setminus A_2))$, and hence
$$(X_1 \times X_2) \setminus (A_1 \times A_2) \subseteq ((X_1 \setminus A_1) \times X_2) \cup (X_1 \times (X_2 \setminus A_2))$$
Similar reasoning proves the other direction of containment, so the two sets are equal.

As a general tip, proving set equalities by double containment (as is (half-)done above) is a good thing to do if it's not immediately clear how a string of algebraic manipulations would help you to arrive at the answer.

Comment: You have put the question on the "element level", and that has become clear. Thank you!
Is there a sequence of transformations that makes the right side from the left one? Like e.g. $(a+1)^2-1=a^2+2a+1-1=a(a+2).$ So, $(a+1)^2-1=a(a+2)$. Or, can the equality only be proven by looking at the elements like we did?

Comment: @Kirill: Algebraic manipulations of sets have to be proved valid somehow, and they're typically proved valid by proving they have the same elements (which is the definition of set equality). So unless you've already proved some identities involving cartesian products, then there's not really anything else you can do.

Comment: Understood. Thanks again!